# I'm unable to use sfdx force:org:open command after authorizing an org via the sfdx CLI

Tags: salesforcedx

I installed the SFDX CLI on my mac, signed up for a dev hub trial, and successfully authorized the devhub org using the following command:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a DevHub
```

When I try to open the org using this command (--json is used to get a more detailed error):

```
sfdx force:org:open -u DevHub --json
```

I get the following error response:

```
{
    "message":"The requested resource does not exist",
    "status":1,
    "stack":"NOT_FOUND: The requested resource does not exist\n
    at HttpApi.getError (/Users/belgart/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/jsforce/lib/http-api.js:250:13)\n
    at /Users/belgart/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/jsforce/lib/http-api.js:95:22\n
    at tryCallOne (/Users/belgart/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)\n
    at /Users/belgart/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15\n
    at flush (/Users/belgart/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)\n
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)\n
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)",
    "name":"NOT_FOUND",
    "warnings":[]
}
```

Has anyone else worked out a resolution to this issue?

Comment: What version of the plugin are you using ? If you're using the pre release one, try using the latest stable release by running sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest

Comment: Running that command seemed to fix it even though my version didn't change. I was on go1.7.3 sfdxstable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Restarting my computer and running

```
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest
```

fixed this for me

Answer (score 0):

If the org was refreshed you need to remove existing org authentication. Options:

1- Press ctrl + shift + p and click on "log out from default org" (if using CLI integration on VSCode
2- Command line: "sf org logout"

Then you need to authenticate the org again to be able to login with VSCode or "sf org open" on command line.