# SFDX force:org:open is throwing auth error

Tags: salesforcedx

It was all good till yesterday. I had reached the last unit of the https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/sfdx_app_dev/units/sfdx_app_dev_setup_dx module and thought of continuing today. But, force:org:open -u TempUnmanaged command is throwing auth error.

Please guide me.

```
D:\Nayana D Drive\Nayana\Trailhead Stuff\SFDX Trail\MutualFundExplorer>sfdx forc
e:org:list --verbose
=== Orgs
     ALIAS   USERNAME              ORG ID              CONNECTED STATUS
───  ──────  ────────────────────  ──────────────────  ────────────────
(D)  DevHub  devhub@trailhead.com  00D7F000002ZgNYUA0  Connected


  ALIAS          SCRATCH ORG NAME  USERNAME                            ORG ID
           STATUS  DEV HUB             CREATED DATE                  INSTANCE UR
L                                              EXPIRATION DATE
  ─────────────  ────────────────  ──────────────────────────────────  ─────────
─────────  ──────  ──────────────────  ────────────────────────────  ───────────
─────────────────────────────────────────────  ───────────────
                 Demo Company      test-jm9x2pkl2h0s@demo_company.net  00D0l0000
000XA6EAM  Active  00D7F000002ZgNYUA0  2017-10-13T10:52:15.000+0000  https://jav
a-data-5232-dev-ed.cs58.my.salesforce.com      2017-10-20
  GeoAppScratch  Demo Company      test-ty4lfw6cokgv@demo_company.net  00D0l0000
000XHrEAM  Active  00D7F000002ZgNYUA0  2017-10-16T11:24:11.000+0000  https://pag
e-data-2087-dev-ed.cs58.my.salesforce.com      2017-10-23
  GeoTestOrg     Demo Company      test-plhfjartzy94@demo_company.net  00D0l0000
000XIFEA2  Active  00D7F000002ZgNYUA0  2017-10-16T12:59:28.000+0000  https://cus
tomer-ruby-9006-dev-ed.cs58.my.salesforce.com  2017-10-23
  TempUnmanaged  Demo Company      test-eflatimr9jvm@demo_company.net  00D0l0000
000XHqEAM  Active  00D7F000002ZgNYUA0  2017-10-16T13:28:46.000+0000  https://dat
a-force-9071-dev-ed.cs58.my.salesforce.com     2017-10-23



D:\Nayana D Drive\Nayana\Trailhead Stuff\SFDX Trail\MutualFundExplorer>sfdx forc
e:org:open -u TempUnmanaged
ERROR:  Failed to decipher auth data. reason: Unsupported state or unable to aut
henticate data.

D:\Nayana D Drive\Nayana\Trailhead Stuff\SFDX Trail\MutualFundExplorer>sfdx forc
e:org:open -u TempUnmanaged --json
{"message":"Failed to decipher auth data. reason: Unsupported state or unable to
 authenticate data.","status":1,"stack":"authDecryptFailed: Failed to decipher a
uth data. reason: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data.\n    at ALME
rror (C:\\Users\\Nayana\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\plugins\\node_modules\\salesforce
-alm\\dist\\lib\\almError.js:35:19)\n    at Crypto.decrypt (C:\\Users\\Nayana\\A
ppData\\Local\\sfdx\\plugins\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\lib\\crypto.js
:157:19)\n    at Object.keys.forEach (C:\\Users\\Nayana\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\p
lugins\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\lib\\configValidator.js:61:36)\n
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)\n    at crypto.init.then (C:\\Users\\Nayana\\AppD
ata\\Local\\sfdx\\plugins\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\lib\\configValida
tor.js:51:37)\n    at tryCatcher (C:\\Users\\Nayana\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\plugi
ns\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\util.js:16:23)\n    at Promise._settleP
romiseFromHandler (C:\\Users\\Nayana\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\plugins\\node_module
s\\bluebird\\js\\release\\promise.js:510:31)\n    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\
\Users\\Nayana\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\plugins\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\relea
se\\promise.js:567:18)\n    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\\Users\\Nayana\\AppDa
ta\\Local\\sfdx\\plugins\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\promise.js:612:10
)\n    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\\Users\\Nayana\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\plug
ins\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\promise.js:691:18)\n    at Async._drai
nQueue (C:\\Users\\Nayana\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\plugins\\node_modules\\bluebird
\\js\\release\\async.js:138:16)\n    at Async._drainQueues (C:\\Users\\Nayana\\A
ppData\\Local\\sfdx\\plugins\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\async.js:148:
10)\n    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\\Users\\Nayana\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx
\\plugins\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\async.js:17:14)\n    at runCallb
ack (timers.js:781:20)\n    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)\n    at processI
mmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:714:5)","name":"authDecryptFailed","
warnings":[]}
```

I have also followed the answer mentioned in the below link. Nothing worked.

[I'm unable to use sfdx force:org:open command after authorizing an org via the sfdx CLI](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/188735/im-unable-to-use-sfdx-forceorgopen-command-after-authorizing-an-org-via-the-s)

Answer (score -1):

its showing the scratch-org is EXPIRATION DATE so that a scratch org is last long for 7 days after seven days its will expire so you have to get truth of source as git so that you can be updated with your work