# Salesforce DX ERROR: Failed to decipher auth data. reason: Unsupported

Tags: error

Today, i reached the second unit "**Get Ready to Create an App**" of "**App Development with Salesforce DX**" trailhead ([Unit link](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/fr/trails/sfdx_get_started/modules/sfdx_app_dev/units/sfdx_app_dev_create_app)).

i am getting an error when trying to create a scratch org using this command

```
sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a GeoAppScratch
```

The message error: 
**ERROR:  Failed to decipher auth data. reason: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data.**

do you have an idea how to get rid of that error ?

Comment: Have you tried the following: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/188735?

Comment: No, i do not think it's the same problem. for me, it works for other projects , i do not know what's the matter with this one.

Comment: It sounds like your data might somehow be corrupt. What's the output of `sfdx force:org:list --verbose`?

Comment: @sfdcfox the scratch org  GeoAppScratch does not appear in the list, it only shows other scratch orgs that i have created before.

Comment: but  for the Orgs part: i have two Orgs with a "Connected Status = Connected" and one org with "Connected Status = authDecryptFailed".

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what the problem is, i have just to login in to my DevHub Org first. using this command: (change 'my-devhub-org' with your Dev hub name)

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a my-devhub-org
```

and Then you can create your scratch orgs as usual.

Answer (score 0):

To complete Merabti's answer, here are some precisions because I for one didn't realize that you must first login to the **exact** DevHub org first, and not only the user account !

Logging in with the same user, to another DevHub org **is not enough**.

In case you're not sure of your DevHub's name anymore, you can find it by listing all your orgs:
`$ sfdx force:org:list`

Then login with:
`$ sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a my-devhub-org`

Then you can do regular stuff like `sfdx force:org:open -u my-devhub-org`.